# Int binding in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing an wpf application with mvvm pattern.
I declare an Int property in My ViewModel class.
When I change this property, the changes not show in UI.
Other data types works good in my application.
But if changed type in to Object it works.

```
public class TestUserControlViewModel : UserControlViewModel
{
    public TestUserControlViewModel(
        TestUserControlView testUserControlView)
    {
        UserControlView = testUserControlView;
        Inital();
    }

    public RelayCommand AddPriceRelayCommand { get; set; }

    public override void InitalCommand()
    {
        AddPriceRelayCommand = new RelayCommand(AddPrice);
    }

    private void AddPrice()
    {
        Price += 10;
    }

    public override void InitalVariable()
    {
        Price = 59;
    }

    private int _price;
    public int Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Price);
        }
    }



}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Price, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: How are you setting the DataContext for your XAML? Did you put a breakpoint in `AddPrice()` to confirm that it's actually being called?

Comment: Grab Snoop and examine your bindings at runtime.  Make sure the DataContext is as expected.  There appears to be nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score -3):

Verify that the Datacontext is as expected,